# Implementation of Inverse Discrete Fourier Transform for a 3-dimensional signal with plain python

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, fft, inverse

I am trying to calculate inverse Discrete Fourier Transform for a 3D Numpy array.

I have already implemented the same for a 1D signal. Please can somebody assist me with converting this code for a 3D array of signals?

```
#Inverse DFT manual 1D
def IFT(data):
    data=np.asarray(data)
    N=data.shape[0]
    n=np.arange(N)
    k=n.reshape((N,1))
    M=np.exp(2j*np.pi*k*n/N)
    return (1/N)*(np.dot(M,data))
```

Note: I want to code this in plain python and not use anyinbuilt fft functions

Comment: Does it need to be fast or efficient? What prevents from just coding up the formula directly, it's a simple triple sum.

Comment: The 3D (I)FFT is simply applying the 1D (I)FFT to each row in the matrix, then to each column, then to each line along the 3D dimension (you can do those steps in any other order too). So what you need to do is write 3 loops, each of which iterate over all lines in one of the three dimensions, and which replace that line in the array with its IFFT: `data[:,j,i] = IFT(data[:,j,i])`.

Comment: @Hilmar yes, I would prefer it to be fast and efficient. But without using the numpy/scipy/torch/etc inbuilt fft algos.